# React useState rerender even if i pass the same reference?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

What I know is that useState will not rerender if we pass the same state, and I test it by myself, but it worked only the first time the component rerendered, with an initial state passed to useState.
But in the example below, the useState rerenders the component even if I pass the same reference, also useEffect knows that the state does not changed.
The picture with console.logs shows that behavior.

```
const arr = [
  { name: 'Khaled', id: 0 },
  { name: 'Mohamed', id: 1 },
  { name: 'Ahmed', id: 2 },
  { name: 'Mohsen', id: 3 },
];

function App() {
  console.log('num $1');

  const [same, setSame] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('num $3');

    const test = arr.find((el) => el.id === 0);
    console.log(Object.is(same, test));
    setSame(test);
  }, [same]);

  console.log('num $2');

  return <div>welcome</div>;
}
```

[image]

Comment: are you using react v18 ?

Comment: @Moeinmoeinnia  yes

Answer (score 4):

The component is rendered twice because you have the initial value for the **same** state which is empty { }. inside the useEffect you update this state with a new object then the useEffect triggers a new value that has been added to the **same** state. which is the matched object from your array. then the component re-rendered and that's why you got in the console.log the true value.

```
   const arr = [
      { name: 'Khaled', id: 0 },
      { name: 'Mohamed', id: 1 },
      { name: 'Ahmed', id: 2 },
      { name: 'Mohsen', id: 3 },
    ];
    
    function App() {
      console.log('num $1');
    
      const [same, setSame] = useState({}); <= initial value
    
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log('num $3');
    
        const test = arr.find((el) => el.id === 0);
        console.log(Object.is(same, test)); <= changed from false to true because the new value of same
        setSame(test); <= you updated the state
      }, [same]); <= the value of same changed from { } to a new value and that's make the component to re-render
    
      console.log('num $2');
    
      return <div>welcome</div>;
    }
```

That's an update for your last comment.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const arr = [
  { name: "Khaled", id: 0 },
  { name: "Mohamed", id: 1 },
  { name: "Ahmed", id: 2 },
  { name: "Mohsen", id: 3 }
];

export default function App() {
  const [same, setSame] = useState(arr);

  useEffect(() => {
    const test = arr.find((el) => el.id === 0);
    console.log(same); <= here the same is [] with 4 objecs
    setSame(test);
    console.log(same); <= here the same is { }
  }, [same]);

  return <div>welcome</div>;
}
```

with that. this will lead us that the useEffect once it sees the **same** get updated. then it will re-render the component as I mentioned before.

here **same** have the **same** data. but they are different because the first **same** is [] and the second one is { }. so that's a change in the state. then useEffect will re-render.

Comment: The question is why it console log after true ?

Comment: because that's the default sequence for the component after it gets re-render to go through the code again line by line.

Comment: I mean the state is the same as the console logs true, so setState should not rerender?
do I misunderstand something?

Comment: @MuhammadHossam the state is not the same. your first initial value for the state is an empty object after that you update the state by using setSame. So the state becomes different now and as long you update the state your state becomes different. not the same

Comment: so it only compares with the initial value only the first time rendering?

Comment: Every time. not only the first time

Comment: okay we change it with the same reference ,so it should not rerender like useEffect does not called ?


at first render, console 1 2 3 and change in useeffect with setSame,
then change state and rerender again so 1 2 3 happen again and now the state will be changed with the same reference, so no rerender should happen

Comment: console.log for num1 & num2 is normal to get logged every time because this is related to the sequence of the component flow. for num3 it gets logged because you set the new state with the results of the array.

Comment: at the step where console.log(Object.is(same, test)) gives true,
then setSame(test).
now we are saying put the state with the same state,
so it should not rerender and should not console.log num 1 & num 2

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer explains it perfectly. To not have the state re-render you must initialize it with the original array.

```
const arr = [
  { name: 'Khaled', id: 0 },
  { name: 'Mohamed', id: 1 },
  { name: 'Ahmed', id: 2 },
  { name: 'Mohsen', id: 3 },
];

function App() {
  console.log('num $1');

  const [same, setSame] = useState(arr); <= initial value is now original arr

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('num $3');

    const test = arr.find((el) => el.id === 0);
    console.log(Object.is(same, test)); <= changed from false to true because the new value of same
    setSame(test); <= you updated the state
  }, [same]); <= the value of same changed from { } to a new value

  console.log('num $2');

  return <div>welcome</div>;
}
```

Make note that this only works for the reference types. Hook doesn’t perform a comparison on objects or arrays, it simply checks whether the reference changes or not. This does not work for value types.

Comment: so it only compares at the first render?
i mean
at the step where console.log(Object.is(same, test)) gives true, then setSame(test). now we are saying put the state with the same state (as they have the same reference), so it should not rerender and should not console.log num 1 & num 2

Comment: As you can see `useEffect` only fires twice. First time on mount so to say, second time on the state change. If you put the same state it will only fire on mount.

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly confused on what exactly you are trying to do, but here's my understanding of this and hopefully an answer to your problem.

Its important to remember that a `useEffect()` will be called on component mount (first render) no matter what. This is why your component is spitting out the `num $3` console log on first render, even though logically you would expect it not to run at-all, as the only `setSame()` function is within the `useEffect()` itself.

For the reason the component re-renders after the state is set with a seemingly-identical object, another important thing to remember here (and with JavaScript in general) is **referential equality**. Consider the following:

```
{} === {} //false
```

Even though logically, you would expect two identical objects to evaluate as two equals, as far as JavaScript is concerned, they are not the same. So, when you pass an object into the `setSame()` function that **looks** the same as what the `same` state is at that time, JavaScript considers it a change of state and prompts a re-render in React.

Hope this helps.

Comment: at the step where console.log(Object.is(same, test)) gives true, then setSame(test). now we are saying put the state with the same state (as they have the same reference), so it should not rerender and should not console.log num 1 & num 2

Comment: Ah I see what you're trying to wrap your head around now. I just had a play about with it an I can't give you a good answer. Putting your `useEffect()` callback function into a `<button>`'s `onClick()` function, the same behaviour occurs, so I think its down to the `useState()` hook itself and the way it works. I wish I could help more, but its an interesting issue nonetheless.